# Python- create a symmetric list given half of nxn list data in csv file

Tags: python, csv, import

I am given data in csv file.
Then I import the file into Python using these codes

```
with open('file.csv') as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        dat = list(reader)
```

The I use the following code to replace "-" by 0

```
for i in range(len(dat)):
        for j in range (len(dat[0])):
            if dat[i][j] == '-':
                dat[i][j] = 0
```

Then I got something like this

```
dat=[[0,"8","4","10],["",0,"5","6"],["","",0,"9"],["","","",0]]
```

How do I get dat to be symmetric and replace all "" with 0, and make numbers that are in "" to be integers?

Expected output:

```
dat=[[0,8,4,10],[8,0,5,6],[4,5,0,9],[10,6,9,0]]
```

Thank you so so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the data, and write it back to the csv reader if you want to store it in the file.

In your example, you should be doing: `if dat[i][j] in ('-', "")` and then writing that back to the file.

Another way to achieve this would be:

```
with open('file.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    output = []
    for row in reader:
        output.append([0 if cell in ("", "-") else int(cell) for cell in row])
    print(output)
```

DEMO:

```
>>> output = []
>>> rows = [["", "-", "8", "10"], ["1", "-", "", "100"]]
>>> for row in rows:
...     output.append([0 if cell in ("", "-") else int(cell) for cell in row])
... 
>>> print(output)
[[0, 0, 8, 10], [1, 0, 0, 100]]
>>>
```

Comment: Hi. Do you know how I can create the expected symmetric  output
Expected output:

dat=[[0,8,4,10],[8,0,5,6],[4,5,0,9],[10,6,9,0]]

Comment: Yup - check the answer - the code snippet shows you how.

Comment: @user02 You should accept this answer (tick the checkbox to the left) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hi i cant locate the checkbox